# Denormalizing hierarchy in list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am parsing a file where labels are defined as below, with hierarchies represented by using new lines

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| L1 - A             |                    |                    |
|                    |  L2 - B            |                    |
|                    |                    |  L3 - C            |
|                    |                    |                    |
| L1 - D             |                    |                    |
|                    |  L2 - E            |                    |
|                    |                    |  L3 - F            |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I represent the above as:

```
labels = [
   ['A', None, None, None, 'D', None, None],
   [None, 'B', None, None, None, 'E', None],
   [None, None, 'C', None, None, None, 'F']
]
```

I tried

```
def joinfoo(items):
   if len(items) == 1:
      return items[0]

   result = []
   active = None
   for x, y in zip(items[0], joinfoo(items[1:])):
      active = x if x else active
      if type(y) is tuple:
         result.append((active, y[0], y[1]))
      else:
         result.append((active, y))

   return result
```

I wanted

```
[
   ('A', None, None), ('A', 'B', None), ('A', 'B', 'C'),
   (None, None, None),
   ('D', None, None), ('D', 'E', None), ('D', 'E', 'F')
]
```

and got this

```
[
   ('A', None, None), ('A', 'B', None), ('A', 'B', 'C'),
   ('A', 'B', None),
   ('D', 'B', None), ('D', 'E', None), ('D', 'E', 'F')
]
```

Suggestions on how to fix `joinfoo()` to achieve the desired result? Solution needs to support a variable number of columns.

It should be something like `for x, y in zip(joinfoo(items[:-1]), items[-1]):` instead of `for x, y in zip(items[0], joinfoo(items[1:])):` to go in the right direction...?

Edit:
The original list of lists may have wrongly implied a pattern to the hierarchy. There is no defined pattern. Number of columns are also variable. A better test case maybe..

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   L1 - A     |              |              |    = A
|              |    L2 - B    |              |    = A - B
|              |              |    L3 - C    |    = A - B - C
|              |              |    L3 - D    |    = A - B - D
|              |    L2 - E    |              |    = A - E
|              |              |              |    =   
|   L1 - F     |              |              |    = F
|              |    L2 - G    |              |    = F - G
|              |              |    L3 - H    |    = F - G - H
+--------------+--------------+--------------+

labels = [
   ['A', None, None, None, None, None, 'F', None, None],
   [None, 'B', None, None, 'E', None, None, 'G', None],
   [None, None, 'C', 'D', None, None, None, None, 'H']
]
```

Comment: What is the variable `items` and where does the data structure presented after "and got this" come from?

Comment: I ran `joinfoo(labels)` if that was the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had some time at my hand and wondered how I would have solved that.

So here is my solution, maybe it sparks some ideas:

```
labels = """\
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| L1 - A             |                    |                    |
|                    |  L2 - B            |                    |
|                    |                    |  L3 - C            |
|                    |                    |                    |
| L1 - D             |                    |                    |
|                    |  L2 - E            |                    |
|                    |                    |  L3 - F            |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
"""

lines = [[(s.strip()[-1:] if s.strip() else None)
             for s in line[1:-1].split('|')]
                 for line in labels.splitlines()[1:-1]]

for index, labels in enumerate(lines):
    if not any(labels):
        continue
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        if label:
            break
        if not label:
            lines[index][i] = lines[index-1][i]

print([tuple(labels) for labels in lines])

# --> [('A', None, None), ('A', 'B', None), ('A', 'B', 'C'), (None, None, None), ('D', None, None), ('D', 'E', None), ('D', 'E', 'F')]
```

Comment: This works. I did `labels = map(list, map(None, *labels))` instead of `lines = [[...]]` and then the `for index... ` as per your code and voila. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`active = x if x else active` from this line you were keeping the original value of active if x is None, however, examining your desired output, you needed a way to reset active to None if you reach the count of the tuple.

here is how i achieved your desired output

```
def joinfoo(items):
   if len(items) == 1:
      return items[0]

   result = []
   active_counter=0
   count=0
   active = None
   for x, y in zip(items[0], joinfoo(items[1:])):
      count=len(y) if type(y) is tuple else 0
      if active_counter >count:
          active_counter=0
          active=None
      else:
          active_counter +=1

      active = x if x else active
      if type(y) is tuple:
         result.append((active, y[0], y[1]))
      else:
         result.append((active, y))

   return result
```

and i got the output

```
    [('A', None, None), ('A', 'B', None), ('A', 'B', 'C'), 
(None, None, None), 
('D', None, None), ('D', 'E', None), ('D', 'E', 'F')]
```

hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

here's a version of joinfoo that gives what you want:

```
def empty(item):  # added this function
   if item is None:
      return True
   else:
      return not any(item)


def joinfoo(items):
   if len(items) == 1:
      return items[0]

   result = []
   active = None
   y_last = None  # added this
   for x, y in zip(items[0], joinfoo(items[1:])):
      active = x if x else active
      if not empty(y_last) and empty(y):  # added this if statement
         active = None
      y_last = y  # added this
      if type(y) is tuple:
         result.append((active, y[0], y[1]))
      else:
         result.append((active, y))

   return result
```

Every time the y entry switches back to None, you want "active" to switch back to None too.

btw, as it's written joinfoo doesn't work for joining any more than 3 lists. if you need it to,

replace `result.append((active, y[0], y[1]))` with `result.append((active, *y))`.

Comment: This version of `joinfoo(labels)` returns `[('A', None, None), ('A', 'B', None), ('A', 'B', 'C'), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, 'E', None), (None, 'E', 'F')]`. The output doesn't look right.

Comment: oh, you're right, but it's makes me just want to rewrite the whole code so it works with multiple lists. the problem is empty tuples being slightly different from just Nones.

Comment: It's pretty close. It misses the `A - E` in the edited example. My original problem was not well defined and missed the variability of the input data.

Comment: I see the edited example now. that makes sense. thanks for the feedback anyway. glad you found another solution.